# Google drive - unable to connect after changing password

Tags: windows-8, google-drive

After changing my google drive password I am unable to connect with google drive app.
[image]
The solution i have adopted yet
1. Restart/quit google drive (frequently)
2. Restart PC (frequently)

but i am unable to get login window again nor my google drive work again and sync instead its only showing unable to connect. checked many forums but unable to find my solution

Comment: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Google Drive?

Comment: oh man i can't do this it will start downloading the flies again i have slow connection